# How do I calculate and set the correct textsize of a TextView?

Tags: android, textview

I have a table with a header row coded in the xml file. I set the `TextSize` attribute of the TextView inside it to 20dp. Now I want to add textview programmatically with the same textSize, but when I use `tv.setTextSize(20)`they are litte bigger.
I tried `tv.setTextSize(20 / ((float) getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));` but that way is too small. What's the correct way to do it?

Comment: Try changing .densityDpi to .xdpi

Comment: same result....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare your textview size in dps inside `app/res/values/dimen.xml` folder

```
<dimen name="text_size_20_dp">20dp</dimen>
```

Java:

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 
                     getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size_20_dp));
```

Kotlin:

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
            resources.getDimension(R.dimen.text_size_20_dp))
```